# Loading ao buscar JSON

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms

Preciso criar um "Loading", quando clico num botão de buscar informação JSON em um site. O Loading precisa ficar no meio da tela.

Código:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="FoodSuppy.Tela.PesquisaCidade">

    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Bisque">

            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                         BackgroundColor="HotPink">
            <!-- Pesquisa -->
                <SearchBar x:Name="MainSearchBar"
                       SearchButtonPressed="MainSearchBar_OnSearchButtonPressed"
                       Placeholder="Digite o nome da cidade..." 
                       TextColor="Black"/>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Aqua">
                <ListView x:Name="lstCidade" 
                          HasUnevenRows="True">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <!-- DataTemplate  = exibe dados de uma coleção de objetos em um ListView -->
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding IBGE}" 
                                       TextColor="Blue" 
                                       FontSize="0" 
                                       HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding CIDADE}" 
                                       TextColor="Blue" 
                                       FontSize="Large" 
                                       HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>

            <!-- Loading -->
            <StackLayout x:Name="LoadingStack"  
                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"
                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" 
                            Opacity="0.5"
                            HeightRequest="500">

                <!-- Loading -->
                <ActivityIndicator x:Name="actInd"
                                    Color="Blue"
                                    HeightRequest="20"
                                    WidthRequest="20"
                                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                </ActivityIndicator>

            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um de meus amigos me enviou um código resolvendo o problema, vou postar para caso alguém precise:

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Green"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1, 1, 1, 1"
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">

        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                     BackgroundColor="Red">
            <!-- Pesquisa -->
            <Label Text="Parte 1" />
            <SearchBar x:Name="MainSearchBar"
                       HeightRequest="30" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   SearchButtonPressed="MainSearchBar_OnSearchButtonPressed"
                   Placeholder="Digite o nome da cidade..." 
                   TextColor="Black"
                       Text="XW" />
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Yellow">
            <Label Text="Parte 1" />
            <ListView x:Name="lstCidade" 
                      HasUnevenRows="True">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <!-- DataTemplate  = exibe dados de uma coleção de objetos em um ListView -->
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="{Binding IBGE}" 
                                   TextColor="Blue" 
                                   FontSize="0" 
                                   HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding CIDADE}" 
                                   TextColor="Blue" 
                                   FontSize="Large" 
                                   HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>

    <!-- Loading -->
    <StackLayout x:Name="LoadingStack" IsVisible="{Binding Loading}"
                        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"
                        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="SizeProportional" 
                        BackgroundColor="White"
                        Opacity="0.5">

        <!-- Loading -->
        <ActivityIndicator x:Name="actInd"
                           IsVisible="True"
                           IsRunning="True"
                                Color="Blue"
                                HeightRequest="20"
                                WidthRequest="20"
                                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        </ActivityIndicator>

    </StackLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando `AbsoluteLayout`, [a propriedade `LayoutBounds` recebe os argumentos nessa ordem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout#specifying-values):

- Posicionamento horizontal
- Posicionamento vertical
- Largura
- Altura

Esses valores podem ser relativos (ao elemento pai) ou absolutos. Isso é determinado pela propriedade `LayoutFlags`.

No seu caso, especificando `"0,0,1,1"` e `All`, você está dizendo que o último `StackLayout` tem todos os valores relativos (posição e tamanho), está posicionado no inicio do elemento pai e vai ocupar todo o seu tamanho.

Os valores relativos variam de 0 (que representa a posição/tamanho do inicio do eixo) a 1 (que representa a posição/tamanho do fim do eixo). Para ilustrar, na sua configuração o `ActivityIndicator` estaria no ponto **`A`** e você quer ele no ponto **`B`**, imaginando que esse seja o `AbsoluteLayout` onde ele está:

```
  0 ______0.5_______1 ← X
   |A              |
   |               |
   |               |
   |               |
   |               |
   |               |
0.5|       B       | 
   |               |
   |               |
   |               |
   |               |
   |               |
  1¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
  ↑
  Y
```

Para posicioná-lo corretamente, substitua seu último `StackLayout` por este código*:

```
<ActivityIndicator x:Name="actInd"
                   Color="Blue"
                   AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.5, 1, 1"
                   AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" 
                   Opacity="0.5"
                   HeightRequest="20"
                   WidthRequest="20"
                   BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
</ActivityIndicator>
```

** É interessante evitar o uso do `StackLayout` quando ele terá somente um elemento filho. Quase sempre poderá ser substituido pelo elemento em si. [Confira algumas dicas para explorar o melhor da performance com o `Xamarin.Forms` nesse artigo](https://kent-boogaart.com/blog/jason-smith's-xamarin-forms-performance-tips)*